# Java Kill processes started with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, unix, process, processbuilder

I'm running my processes like this:

```
builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "./MessageGenerator | ./SimpleEchoServer");
process = builder.start();
```

Then process.destroy() or forciblyDestroy() doesn't work. Is it because I'm using a pipe? How can I kill these processes?

Answer (score 0):

you should also split up the pipe command. I've written a little example:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
        String line;
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -l", "|", "grep java");
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        process.destroy();
    }
}
```